# SPSiteDataQuery without subfolder items?

Tags: splistitem, splist, spquery, spsitedataquery

I'm trying to use the SPSiteDataQuery to return the contents of several lists across a site collection. The problem I'm having, though, is that while there are only a few documents at the root level of these lists, the lists have folders containing large amounts of items, which causes the Query to exceed the List View Threshold.

I know that SPQuerys allow you to do something like

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""
```

to recurse, and removing that will just show the results of the root folder only. Is there a way of filtering out ListItems that are in subfolders with any sort of CAML query?

Comment: What level are you trying to stop returning values at? Direct subfolders of the root folder? (ie: Root/Folder/Document.doc) Or subfolders of folders directly beneath the root? (ie: Root/Folder/Subfolder/Document.doc)

Comment: Direct subfolders and their subfolders - the goal is to only have list items in the root folder being returned.

Comment: OK, I thought about this for a minute to come up with the best answer I can. There is no way to filter this via a property with the `SPSiteDataQuery`. Your best bet is to try to refine your query more to return less items.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I guess then it'd be possible to perform multiple SPQueries, but I'm not sure if that's reasonable or feasible.

Comment: As long as you aren't querying across site collections that is a viable option. Just use another collection like `List<SPListItem>` and add the result sets.

Comment: Yeah, everything's in one site collection. Multiple sites and subsites in some cases, but never across multiple site collections.

I'll have to experiment with that, then. Thank you!